# Get SharePoint 2013 Site Page in ASP.net MVC web application

Tags: office-365, asp.net

I can use this `.../_api/Web/lists/getByTitle('abc')/items` to get the SharePoint list items.

Also, I have created the some pages in SharePoint 2013 Site page.

How can I get the Site page content using an ASP.net MVC web application?

Answer (score 2):

The following REST request demonstrates how to return pages from `Site Pages` library:

```
/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Site Pages')/items
```

Since content pages in `Site Pages` library are *wiki pages*, the following REST request demonstrates how to retrieve page content:

```
/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Site Pages')/items?$select=WikiField
```